# Python issue with outlook

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

Using this code

https://www.codingfortherestofus.com/how-to-automatically-download-outlook-email-attachments-with-python/

I am trying this code for shared mailbox, earlier it used to take less time and now it taking almost 30 minutes and and times it skips emails

I am running in personal mailbox then it is running fast
Is this bz shared mailbox is full?¹

Comment: Welcome. On SO, code is required to be entered as text, with the link as support.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.